# broadcast receiver for missed call in android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Does anyone know what is the intent for missed call. Actually i want to send sms on missed call and incomming call in my application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no specific broadcast for a missed call, AFAIK.

You can watch for [`ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) broadcasts, wait until the phone shifts from `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` to `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`, then try checking the `CallLog` content provider to see if the call was missed. I have not tried this technique, but it may work.

Comment: @CommonsWare-Can we differentiate between Missed Call and Rejected Call because both function in the above mentioned way !!!

Answer (score 12):

You need to use a ContentObserver

```
public class MissedCallsContentObserver extends ContentObserver
{
    public MissedCallsContentObserver()
    {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
    {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            Calls.CONTENT_URI, 
            null, 
            Calls.TYPE +  " = ? AND " + Calls.NEW + " = ?", 
            new String[] { Integer.toString(Calls.MISSED_TYPE), "1" }, 
            Calls.DATE + " DESC ");

        //this is the number of missed calls
        //for your case you may need to track this number
        //so that you can figure out when it changes
        cursor.getCount(); 

        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

From your app, you just need to do this:

```
MissedCallsContentObserver mcco = new MissedCallsContentObserver();
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Calls.CONTENT_URI, true, mcco);
```

Comment: Hi, i would like to know if you intentionally left out `cursor.close()`? Like it is not necessary because the `ContentObserver` will close it automatically?

Comment: good question.  I did not leave it out intentionally, it should be there.  I will update my answer.