# Show Toast on Missed Call in android application

Tags: android, toast

i want to show a Toast in an Activity when a missed call happened. How can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have content providers to access call logs.

http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_querying_and_displaying_the_calllog-t169.html

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/41133

If this code works you just need to run this query at the right time. I mean check some samples that can notify you when you get a call in your device

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d97a759a3708cbe3

Once you get this notification put a timer or use some built in Intents to find that the phone is back to normal state and access the call logs...

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question recently, the answer should work for you as well:

[broadcast receiver for missed call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665183/broadcast-receiver-for-missed-call-in-android)

showing the toast afterwards should be the easy part :)