# How to retrieve missed calls on Android SDK 2.2

Tags: android, notifications, telephony

in my app I should do some action when a call comes but not answered by the user.

I have searched in the *android.telephony* and the *NotificationManager*, but I haven't found a method to solve this problem.

Does someone have an idea of how to get to know if there is a missed call on the phone or not ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is code that can query the call log for a missed call. Basically, you will have to trigger this somehow and make sure that you give the call log some time ( a few seconds should do it) to write the information otherwise if you check the call log too soon you will not find the most recent call.

```
final String[] projection = null;
final String selection = null;
final String[] selectionArgs = null;
final String sortOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
Cursor cursor = null;
try{
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"),
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            sortOrder);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
        String callLogID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID));
        String callNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
        String callDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));
        String callType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
        String isCallNew = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NEW));
        if(Integer.parseInt(callType) == MISSED_CALL_TYPE && Integer.parseInt(isCallNew) > 0){
            if (_debug) Log.v("Missed Call Found: " + callNumber);
        }
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
    if (_debug) Log.e("ERROR: " + ex.toString());
}finally{
    cursor.close();
}
```

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: How is MISSED_CALL_TYPE declared?

Comment: MISSED_CALL_TYPE = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE; - Sorry for leaving that part out.

Comment: Thanks! I could not use it then so i found out that there are 2 ways for these call types: 1. declare it as an integer: int typeColumn = c.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE);, then  int callType = c.getInt(typeColumn); and after all e.g. if calltype==1 then.....  2: use   int outgoingtypeColumn = c.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "='2'"); etc. Hope this helps others!

Comment: Thanks Camille, this code was useful.  To others planning to use it: don't forget to add android.permission.READ_CONTACTS to your AndroidManifest.xml, and check if the cursor is null before closing it.

Comment: I'm getting error of context cannot be resolved. I have put the above code in class extends Activity.

Comment: Camille, thank's for your code. But this code return calls and SMS. How to filter calls only in this case?

Comment: @BArtWell - The code above certainly does not return SMS messages.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you need to query the [CallLog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.html) provider (or maybe CallLog.Calls), and this page explains how to query content provider: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#basics

I'd be happy to see the code if you can make this work !

Comment: Yes. But in that case, I will not be able to know if the missed phone call is answered or not. In my app, if the missed phone has been answered, I should not notify the user about the missed phone call again.

Comment: How can a missed call be answered? There is a MISSING_TYPE constant in the CallLog.Calls class, I believe a call is either of MISSING_TYPE, INCOMING_TYPE or OUTGOING_TYPE

Comment: Yes. I am sorry that I didn't express what I want clearly. I agree with you that "a missed call" can't be answered when the phone is "ringing". But we can call back when we know there is a missed call after, and this is what I mean "answer" in my question. So in this way, I think it is better to use a notification other than reading the info in the calllog. I hope I am clearer this time.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have content providers to access call logs.

http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_querying_and_displaying_the_calllog-t169.html

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/41133

If this code works you just need to run this query at the right time. I mean check some samples that can notify you when you get a call in your device

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d97a759a3708cbe3

Once you get this notification put a timer or use some built in Intents to find that the phone is back to normal state and access the call logs...

Possible duplicate

[broadcast receiver for missed call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665183/broadcast-receiver-for-missed-call-in-android)

[Show Toast on Missed Call in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667029/show-toast-on-missed-call-in-android-application)