# handle a missed call with broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is there a way to handle missed calls in android? I came across `CALL_STATE_CHANGED` action many times. But how can i check specifically whether it's a missed call? What I want is to do some action when the user misses a call. How can I do this? Do I need to check call logs after every call and find out whether there is a missed call?

Comment: same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665183/broadcast-receiver-for-missed-call-in-android

Comment: I have gone through it. The accepted answer says that we need to check call logs after the phone's state changes. So i asked is there any other way to do it instead of searching in call logs database every time.

Comment: @SeshuVinay, please refrain from adding `random code formatting` to your question.  Doing so makes it hard to read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose you could use [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) to listen for call state change from `CALL_STATE_RINGING` to `CALL_STATE_IDLE` which indicates the phone was not picked up.

Comment: And can i get call details here itself?

Comment: As you can see in the onCallStateChanged(int newState, String number), the second parameter gives the incoming number.

Comment: it's not necessary that CALL_STATE_IDLE, will  record only missed call. It will record call that is hanged up (finished call) also, but this kind of call is not missed.

Comment: Read my answer again. A transition from ringing state to idle state should indicate a missed call.

Comment: @AswinKumar- rootpanthera is right...Rejected Call will also show above mentioned functionality..then how can we differentiate between those two..??